# General nested for

Tags: c++, combinatorics, iterator

I needed a general-purpose function that accepts some `sequence_container<sequence_container<T>>` and iterates all permutations of the inner container. To be more precise, the outer `sequence_container` should be described by an iterator pair to easily allow selecting parts of it.

For example `{{1,2},{},{3,4}}` shall iterate `{1,?,3},{1,?,4},{2,?,3},{2,?,4}`. The function provides a callback to deal with each of these 4 permutations. The callback has two parameters:

- a vector of indices, giving in each iteration one of `{0,-1,0},{0,-1,1},{1,-1,0},{1,-1,1}` in above example
- a vector of values, giving in each iteration one of `{1,?,3},{1,?,4},{2,?,3},{2,?,4}` in above example

Through `-1`, the user can check whether the value should be checked or not. This might be helpful if the original indices should be retained.

I have written the following code that accomplishes it. It works both for `const` and `non-const` containers, albeit only `const` containers should actually be fine since we cannot change anything in the container so far. Usage is `nestedFor::run(beginIterator, endIterator, callback)`.

Roast me, glad for any feedback!

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

namespace nestedFor
{
    // helper to check if an iterator is const
    template<typename Iterator>
    struct isConstIterator
    {
        typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::pointer pointer;
        static const bool value =
        std::is_const<typename std::remove_pointer<pointer>::type>::value;
    };

    // helper to get const_iterator or iterator, whatever applicable, for nested type
    template<typename OuterItT, typename=void>
    struct retrieveConstCorrectIterator
    {
        using iterator = typename OuterItT::value_type::iterator;
    };

    template<typename OuterItT>
    struct retrieveConstCorrectIterator<OuterItT, std::enable_if_t<isConstIterator<OuterItT>::value>>
    {
        using iterator = typename OuterItT::value_type::const_iterator;
    };

    // given a container<container<T>>, loops all combinations of inner vector;
    // Func should be of type:
    // void func(const std::vector<int>& indices, std::vector<T>& values);
    // in each iteration, func is called with indices showing the position
    // and respective values;
    // note that empty inner vectors are allowed, the respective index is -1, then
    template<typename OuterItT, typename Func>
    void run(OuterItT begin, OuterItT end, Func func)
    {
        using InnerItT = typename retrieveConstCorrectIterator<OuterItT>::iterator;
        using ItVecT = std::vector<InnerItT>;
        using ItVecItT = typename ItVecT::iterator;

        // idx -1 means that there is no valid entry
        using IdxVecT = std::vector<int>;
        using ValueVecT = std::vector<typename InnerItT::value_type>;
        using IdxVecItT = typename IdxVecT::iterator;
        using ValueVecItT = typename ValueVecT::iterator;

        const typename std::iterator_traits<OuterItT>::difference_type numInnerVecs =
        std::distance(begin, end);

        IdxVecT idxVec(numInnerVecs, -1);
        ValueVecT valueVec(numInnerVecs);

        ItVecT runIterators(numInnerVecs), startIterators(numInnerVecs), endIterators(numInnerVecs);
        ItVecItT runItVecIt = runIterators.begin(),
        startItVecIt = startIterators.begin(),
        endItVecIt = endIterators.begin();
        IdxVecItT runIdxIterators = idxVec.begin(),
        runValueIterators = valueVec.begin();

        for(OuterItT it = begin; it != end; ++it, ++runItVecIt, ++startItVecIt, ++endItVecIt,
            ++runIdxIterators, ++runValueIterators)
        {
            *runItVecIt = it->begin();
            *startItVecIt = it->begin();
            *endItVecIt = it->end();

            if(it->begin() == it->end())
            {
                *runIdxIterators = -1;
                // value idx undefined then
            }
            else
            {
                *runIdxIterators = 0;
                *runValueIterators = *(*startItVecIt);
            }
        }

        while(true)
        {
            func(idxVec, valueVec);

            ItVecItT itToMove = runIterators.begin(),
            itToMoveStart = startIterators.begin(),
            itToMoveEnd = endIterators.begin();

            IdxVecItT idxIt = idxVec.begin();
            ValueVecItT valueIt = valueVec.begin();

            bool bigBreak = false;
            ++*itToMove;

            if(*itToMove != *itToMoveEnd)
            {
                ++*idxIt;
                *valueIt = **itToMove;
            }

            while(*itToMove == *itToMoveEnd)
            {
                *itToMove = *itToMoveStart;

                if(*itToMove != *itToMoveEnd)
                {
                    *idxIt = 0;
                    *valueIt = **itToMoveStart;
                }

                ++itToMove;
                ++itToMoveStart;
                ++itToMoveEnd;
                ++idxIt;
                ++valueIt;

                if(itToMove == runIterators.end())
                {
                    bigBreak = true;
                    break;
                }

                if(*itToMove != *itToMoveEnd)
                {
                    ++*itToMove;
                    ++*idxIt;
                    *valueIt = **itToMove;
                }
            };

            if(bigBreak)
                break;

        }
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: @Deduplicator yes, good point. The function accepts `iterator`s but a bare array won't work... `std::array` would, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Naming**. What `run` iterates over is known as a direct (or Cartesian) product. It seems that `namespace direct_product` is more descriptive than `nestedFor`.
- **Parallel arrays** (`runIterators, startIterators, endIterators`) remind me good old days of Fortran. It is definitely an anti-idiomatic C++. Consider a single vector of

  ```
  struct iterators {
      Iter runIterator,
      Iter startIterator,
      Iter endIterator,
      // Constructors, assignment, increment, and anything else which is needed
  }
  ```

  You will need much less lines to express the *increment a vector* idiom.
- I strongly recommend to use a class instead of namespace. This way an initialization loop naturally becomes a constructor, and the actual loop becomes unnecessary. Define an iterator over states of the product, `operator++` and `operator*` for it. This lifts the callback out of your responsibility, and enables the client to write

  ```
  direct_product dp{....};
  for (auto it = dp.begin(); it != dp.end(); ++it) {
      fun(*it);
  }
  ```

  or even a range-based loop.
- Kudos for not resorting to recursion.